# How do I ask "who has done the most number of things" properly

Tags: grammar, superlative-degree

Sorry if the title is confusing. Basically I want to ask people "who has done a certain thing for the most number/times" but I don't know to properly construct the sentence.

Please help me.

Comment: I think it depends on what that "certain thing" is.

Comment: What's wrong with "who has done it the most times"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numbers can be *great*, *large* or *high*. So, speaking of *numbers*, you can use *'greatest'* as the superlative form:

> Who has done it (that thing or trick) **the greatest number** of times?

If you mean a physical handmade thing (like a piece of jewelry):

> Who has made/produced the greatest number of copies of that thing?